# using mailer in Symfony 4.3- > Expected response code "250" but got code "535", with message "535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted

Tags: symfony, gmail, mailer

I'm stuck. I'm using mailer from symfony with gmail generated password, and i keep on getting this error.

Would anyone have an idea as of why?

here's my controller:

```
 public function new(Request $request): Response
    {
        $contact = new Contact();
        $form = $this->createForm(ContactType::class, $contact);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $entityManager->persist($contact);
            $entityManager->flush();
            $name = ($form['Name']->getData());
            $email = ($form['Email']->getData());
            $subject = ($form ['Subject']->getData());
            $content = ($form['Content']->getData());
            $transport = new GmailTransport('******@*********.org', '******************');
            $mailer = new Mailer($transport);

            $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Subject::class);
            $toEmail = $subject -> getEmail();
            $realSubject = $subject -> getName();

            $message = (new TemplatedEmail())
            ->from($email)
            ->to($toEmail)
            ->subject($content)

            // path of the Twig template to render
            ->htmlTemplate('mail/newContact.html.twig')

            /* pass variables (name => value) to the template
            ->context([
                'expiration_date' => new \DateTime('+7 days'),
                'username' => 'foo',*/

            ;
    $mailer->send($message);


            return $this->redirectToRoute('home');
        }

        return $this->render('contact/new.html.twig', [
            'contact' => $contact,
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ]);
    }
```

and i've got this in the .env

```
###> symfony/mailer ###
 MAILER_DSN=smtp://******@*********.org:******************@gmail
###< symfony/mailer ###
```

does anyone have an idea?

Thank you

Comment: You need a Gmail or Google Suite account in order to use Gmail SMTP. Is that your case?

Comment: Also, what's the point of setting the .env DSN configuration if later you're hard coding the username and password?

Comment: i have the google suite account, yes

Comment: Make sure you have "Allow less secure apps" option enabled on your G Suite account here https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps